# How to optimize lagged differences in data.table (r)

Tags: r, data.table

I am trying to optimize a snippet of r code to calculate lagged differences using data.table in R.  I have two working solutions, but both run painfully slow on my real data (500 million row datasets). I have enjoyed the speedup and efficiency of using data.table generally, but both solutions I implemented are quite slow (compared to other data.table operations).

Could anyone offer suggestion for more efficient coding practice in data.table for this specific task?

```
library(data.table)
set.seed(1)
id <- 1:10
date_samp <- seq.Date(as.Date("2010-01-01"),as.Date("2011-01-01"),"days")
dt1 <- 
  data.table(id = sample(id,size = 30,replace=T),
             date_1 = sample(date_samp,size = 30,replace=T))
setkey(dt1,id,date_1)
### Attempt to get lagged date
## Attempt 1
dt1[,date_diff:=c(0,diff(date_1)),
    by=id]
## Attempt 2
## Works but gives warnings
dt1[,date_diff:=NULL]
dt1[,n_group := .N,by=id]
dt1[,date_diff:=c(0,date_1[2:n_group]-date_1[1:(n_group-1)]),
    by=id]
```

Comment: I've experienced slowness surprises with data.table as well. Most of the time it's really speedy. The `table` function seems much slower when called from the j-position in `[.data.table` than when used from the console.

Comment: @42 I suspect using the .N argument with by=list(x1,x2,x3...) would give you the fastest table calculations...you could then reshape to your desired format

Comment: You are quite right about `[, .N, by=list(...)]` being faster. The differences were substantial; not noticeable on an example of this size of course but about a factor of 100 on an example with millions.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

After a bit more effort I found the "shift()" function on a related question. I have made the data a bit larger and done some crude profiling, as well as added a few more approaches...but please update and provide a different answer if there is a more efficient approach.

In response to comments below I added and changed some things...attempt for is numeric (not integer), and my keyed by was incorrect. I added an integer comparison and a keyed by with the integer (in addition to the numeric). It now looks like converting the date to an integer then using "grouping by each i" is the fastest solution.

```
library(data.table)
set.seed(1)
id <- 1:100
date_samp <- seq.Date(as.Date("2010-01-01"),as.Date("2011-01-01"),"days")
n_samp <- 1e7
dt1 <- 
  data.table(id = sample(id,size = n_samp,replace=T),
             date_1 = sample(date_samp,size = n_samp,replace=T))
setkey(dt1,id,date_1)
### Attempt to get lagged date
## Attempt 1
dt1[,date_diff:=NULL]
system.time(dt1[,date_diff:=c(0,diff(date_1)),
    by=id])
## Attempt 2
dt1[,date_diff:=NULL]
dt1[,n_group := .N,by=id]
system.time(dt1[,date_diff:=c(0,date_1[2:n_group]-date_1[1:(n_group-1)]),
    by=id])
## Attempt 3
dt1[,date_diff:=NULL]
system.time(dt1[,date_diff:=date_1-shift(date_1),
    by=id])
## Attempt 4
## Use numeric instead
dt1[,date_diff:=NULL]
dt1[,date_1num:=NULL]
dt1[,date_1num:=as.numeric(date_1)]
system.time(dt1[,date_diff:=date_1num-shift(date_1num),
                by=id])
## Attempt 5
## Use a keyed by
dt_key <- unique(dt1[,list(id)])
dt1[,date_diff:=NULL]
system.time(dt1[dt_key,
    date_diff:=date_1num-shift(date_1num),
    by=.EACHI])

## Attempt 6
## Use integers instead
dt1[,date_diff:=NULL]
dt1[,date_1int:=as.integer(date_1)]
system.time(dt1[,date_diff:=date_1int-shift(date_1int),
                by=id])
## Attempt 7
## Use integers with keyed by
dt1[,date_diff:=NULL]
dt1[,date_1int:=as.integer(date_1)]
system.time(dt1[dt_key,
                date_diff:=date_1int-shift(date_1int),
                by=.EACHI])


# attempt   user  system elapsed 
# 1         0.34    0.25    0.59     
# 2         0.37    0.28    0.67 
# 3         0.25    0.16    0.41
# 4         0.11    0.01    0.13 
# 5         0.06    0.03    0.10
# 6         0.09    0.00    0.09
# 7         0.05    0.00    0.04
```

Comment: Those are not integers. `as.numeric` converts to float. Use `IDate` class instead. And your attempt 5 seems to be wrong. There is no grouping happening when you do `dt[key, j]`, you must add the `by=.EACHI` option.

Comment: @Frank - using `as.integer` instead of `as.numeric` seems to wipe some more time off the result. My testing seems to suggest that a variable converted to `as.IDate` is slower by an order of magnitude though when using `shift` as per Attempt4.

Comment: Yeah, I'm seeing that too. Odd. Seems to defeat the purpose of having the IDate class.

Comment: Ok posted about it over here @thela https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/1836 Didn't @ you before; mistook you for the OP due to your quick reply.

Comment: thank you for the assistance! I have updated my answer.

Comment: Could you comment on why attempt 2 gives warnings?

Comment: Fyi, because there are two commenters besides you, neither of them will be "pinged" when you respond. Instead, use @username for one of them. It gives a warning because you wrote `1:(1-n_group)` but within each `id`,  `n_group` is a column taking many (repeated) values. Use `n_group[1]` instead, probably.

Comment: @Frank Perfect, that removed the warnings and I understand why that was happening now, thank you!

Comment: Hi again. You did not add an approach using IDate yet, which I'm now seeing is fast: https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/1836#issuecomment-320478099 (in case you want to edit to include it). Note that I use `as.IDate` not `as.Date` in constructing `date_samp`

Answer (score 1):

If you want to nix the by:

```
  dt1[order(id, date_1)
      ][, idP := shift(id, type='lag')
      ][, headP := is.na(idP) | idP != id
      ][, date_1P := shift(date_1, type='lag')
      ][headP == T, date_diff := 0
      ][headP == F, date_diff := date_1 - date_1P
      ][, c('headP', 'idP', 'date_1P') := NULL
      ][]
```